# Linq to entities Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on asp.net application and I have created a query. I want to change it so that if checkbox is checked then null records for a field can not be entered. my query look like this:

```
var query = from d in context.data_vault.Where(d => states.Contains(d.STATE) 
    && counties.Contains(d.COUNTY)
    && cities.Contains(d.CITY)
    && zipCodes.Contains(d.ZIP)
    && areaCodes.Contains(d.AREA_CODE)
    && (d.MKTVAL > Convert.ToInt32(txtMarketValueFrom) && d.MKTVAL < Convert.ToInt32(txtMarketValueTo.Text))
    && (d.LTV > Convert.ToByte(txtLTVFrom.Text ) && d.LTV < Convert.ToByte(txtLTVTo.Text))
    && d.FHA_LIMIT_FLAG == chkFHA.Checked
    && (d.MTGAMT > Convert.ToInt32(txtMortgageFrom.Text) && d.MTGAMT < Convert.ToInt32(txtMortgageTo.Text))
    && (d.MTGDATE > Convert.ToDateTime(txtMortgageDateFrom.Text) && d.MTGDATE < Convert.ToDateTime(txtMortgageDateTo.Text))
    && d.LOAN_TYPE == drpMortgageLoanType.Text
    //&& (chkLenderName.Checked )  d.LENDERNAME != null  
    && lenderNames.Contains(d.LENDERNAME)
    //&& rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked ? d.HE == "" : rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked
    //&& d.HEAMT = txtSecondMortgageFrom.Text
    && d.HE_LOAN_TYPE == drpSecondMortgageLoanType.SelectedItem.Text
    && d.HELENDERNAME == txtSecondMortgageLenderName.Text
    && (d.AGE > Convert.ToByte(txtAgeFrom.Text) && d.AGE < Convert.ToByte(txtAgeTo.Text)
    //rdoNoPhone.Checked ? d.phones
    ))
    group d by new
    {
        d.STATE
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.STATE,
        Count = (Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.SCORE),
        Phone = (Int64?)g.Count(p => p.PHONE != null)
    };

GridView1.DataSource = query;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

How to change it so that if rdoNoPhone.Checked radio button is checked then records with null phone are not included

Comment: haven't you omitted field name in g.Key.STATE?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili sorry didnt get you

Comment: in select new { g.Key.STATE , .... } you haven't specified field name before g.Key.State.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili How to make selection of all the records conditional based on rdoNoPhone.checked state ?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili I want to uncomment these  //&& (chkLenderName.Checked )  d.LENDERNAME != null  and 
  //&& rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked ? d.HE == "" : rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked
                                                                        //&& d.HEAMT = txtSecondMortgageFrom.Text
and     //rdoNoPhone.Checked ? d.phones

Comment: one question.is your code working with no errors with commenting out that codes?

Comment: no there are errors in where clauses

Comment: check to see if your exception has inner exception.if it does post it here.

Comment: I get this : Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your notation like this:

```
 var query = from d in context.data_vault.Where(delegate(ata_vault d){

  return states.Contains(d.STATE) 
    && counties.Contains(d.COUNTY)
    && cities.Contains(d.CITY)
    && zipCodes.Contains(d.ZIP)
    && areaCodes.Contains(d.AREA_CODE)
    && (d.MKTVAL > Convert.ToInt32(txtMarketValueFrom) && d.MKTVAL < Convert.ToInt32(txtMarketValueTo.Text))
    && (d.LTV > Convert.ToByte(txtLTVFrom.Text ) && d.LTV < Convert.ToByte(txtLTVTo.Text))
    && d.FHA_LIMIT_FLAG == chkFHA.Checked
    && (d.MTGAMT > Convert.ToInt32(txtMortgageFrom.Text) && d.MTGAMT < Convert.ToInt32(txtMortgageTo.Text))
    && (d.MTGDATE > Convert.ToDateTime(txtMortgageDateFrom.Text) && d.MTGDATE < Convert.ToDateTime(txtMortgageDateTo.Text))
    && d.LOAN_TYPE == drpMortgageLoanType.Text
    //&& (chkLenderName.Checked )  d.LENDERNAME != null  
    && lenderNames.Contains(d.LENDERNAME)
    //&& rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked ? d.HE == "" : rdoexcludeSecondMortgage.Checked
    //&& d.HEAMT = txtSecondMortgageFrom.Text
    && d.HE_LOAN_TYPE == drpSecondMortgageLoanType.SelectedItem.Text
    && d.HELENDERNAME == txtSecondMortgageLenderName.Text
    && (d.AGE > Convert.ToByte(txtAgeFrom.Text) && d.AGE < Convert.ToByte(txtAgeTo.Text)
    && rdoNoPhone.Checked ? d.PHONE!= null : true
    })
    group d by new
    {
        d.STATE
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.STATE,
        Count = (Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.SCORE),
        Phone = (Int64?)g.Count(p => p.PHONE != null)
    };
```

Comment: what part did you modify? should i try something like this  &&(rdoNoPhone.Checked == true || d.PHONE!= null)

Comment: what do you wanna do here? is this it ? : if rdoNoPhone.Checked == true then your d.Phone shouldn't be null?yes?

Comment: yes I want that if rdoChecked == true then only records with phone <> null should be pulled so adding &&(rdoNoPhone.Checked == false|| d.PHONE!= null) will ensure this ?

Comment: dear @DotnetSparrow lets solve problem step by step.first comment out all AND ed conditions til make sure your code works well with minimum condition then uncomment each line and see what line causes error.then post that line here. thanks.

Comment: i have edited this line check that. and what about rdoexcludeSecondMortgage?

Comment: what does it mean  && rdoNoPhone.Checked ? d.PHONE!= null : true . can you please give some hint ?

Comment: this means that if  rdoNoPhone.Checked == true then select d(s) that has PHONE not equal to null else don't effect the condition. (e.g: X AND true = X )

Comment: what if i want to make all these where clauses optional  d.LOAN_TYPE == drpMortgageLoanType.Text then show related records but if   && d.LOAN_TYPE = null then ignore this where clause

Comment: I eamn to ask do i need to do like this d => (d.STATE == null || states.Contains(d.STATE)) and so on for all clauses ?

Comment: I want to make all these where clauses optional, like if user entered some text then filter by it otherwise ignore that field in search. Right now If i search by that field by typing something, it filters and if i dont type, it returns no result

Comment: the code will vary from one control to other .but u can use same code for all.for example for a textbox you can use this: chk1.checked ? d.TextProperty == yourTextBox.Value : true     --- but for a ComboBox you can use this : chk2.checked ? youComboBox.Items.Contains(d.Value) : true.

Comment: finally i know what you want to do.you must define a checkbox per Field of your entity and use code above to include them in query.if checkbox for that field have been checked then apply condition else use only TRUE literal.

Comment: what if I dont want to use checkbox and simply want that if something is typed then use it ? something like this  string[] states = lstStates.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToArray();    var query = from d in context.data_vault
                                .Where(d => (d.STATE == null || (states.Contains(d.STATE) && states.Count() != 0)))

Comment: in this example you don't checked whether states.Length > 0 or not to know if list is empty or not.am i wrong?

Comment: the correct condition can be : var query = from d in context.data_vault .Where(d=>states.Lenght > 0 ? states.Contains(d.STATE) : true)

Comment: with above condition if states contains any item then it will participate in condition else it will be ignored.

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<DataSystem.Model.data_vault,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: pass it an extra int argument.

Comment: what about this : var query = from d in context.data_vault
                                .Where(d => (states.Contains(d.STATE) || states.Count()  == 0))

Comment: delegate (ata_vault d , int index)

Comment: last question, Why did you use delegate in this query ?

Comment: because without using this notation exception will be thrown, because u are using some C# functions that have not mapping in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help @Behnam. Very good response. I have been struggling since morning. Can you please suggest some good learning material for Linq to entities. marking you as answer

Comment: i am glad to help. are you interested reading ebook? if yes the i can recommend reading "LINQ Unleashed".